# ajax wp_query conditional tags not working

Tags: wp-query, ajax, conditional-tags

I'm trying to ajax **wp_query**, I got success getting posts for home page with the following code.

Then I added **conditional tags** to modify the query for the other pages like **Category page**

the problem that all **conditional tags** are not working inside this function, it keeps giving me the same posts of the home page.

I'm using this code in **function.php** file:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_wp_ajax_posts', 'wp_ajax_posts_init' );
function wp_ajax_posts_init() {
  /** Made Query */
    $numPosts = (isset($_POST['numPosts'])) ? $_POST['numPosts'] : 0;
    $page = (isset($_POST['pageNumber'])) ? $_POST['pageNumber'] : 0;
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'=>  $numPosts,
        'paged'         =>  $page,
    );
if(is_post_type_archive('projects')){
    $args['post_type'] = 'projects';
}
if(is_category()){
    $category   =   get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
    $cat_id     =   $category->cat_ID;
    $args['cat'] = $cat_id;
}
$theme_post_query = new WP_Query( $args );
while( $theme_post_query->have_posts() ) : $theme_post_query->the_post();
//--html content
endwhile;   
wp_reset_query();
}
```

the weird thing that conditional tags are working in all other functions like where I enqueue the ajax script

```
if(is_home() || is_category() || is_search() || is_tag() || is_post_type_archive('projects')){
    wp_register_script( 'ajaxLoop-js', "{$ss_url}/js/ajaxLoop.js", array('jquery'));
    $php_array = array( 'admin_ajax' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) );
    wp_localize_script( 'ajaxLoop-js', 'php_array', $php_array );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajaxLoop-js' );
}
```

any ideas how to get **conditional tags** work at `wp_ajax_posts_init()`?

Comment: Are you sure that `wp_ajax_wp_ajax_posts` is a good name? I find that highly confusing and would suggest to avoid such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ajax request happens in completely separate load, it will have no awareness about which page you are making request from and will have no main query or query conditionals.

If you want to retrieve something based on the context of page you are making request from then you need to pass that information in your ajax request and retrieve posts based on it.

Comment: do you know how would I pass any information from second code to script?, since `echo json_encode($result);` will be useless in the first function.

Comment: You are already passing data via localize object, you just need to add more of what you need and make use of it in your JS.